# glyphicon not coming in more than one page asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

I have added a asp button in multiple webforms by using code:

```
    <script src="../assets/js/select2.min.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.raty.min.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/chosen.jquery.min.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/select2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/chosen.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap-multiselect.min.css" />
    <script src="../assets/js/Jquery.Validation.Textbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
...

...

<asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary glyphicon"  Text="&#xe025;" ToolTip="Download Template"                                               OnClick="btnDownload_Click" />
```

But the problem here is that the download icon don't comes in more than one page.
This is the screenshot of the page where the icon is coming and the inspected page shows the class tag has glyphicon name in it:
[image]

and this is the page where the same code is not working and the name glyphicon is not being inspected in the page:
[image]
as we can see in second screen shot class tag is missing the glyphicon name.
I tried lot but couldn't find the solution for this.

I'm using visual studio 2017 and this application is developed in asp.net webform.

Comment: search btnDownload in solution. You may find two different implementations of it.

Comment: well, even after i change btnDownload to btnDownload_ so that the page which i am testing right now will have unique button id, still the result is coming same. well, how should i remove this bug.

Comment: Is same master page applied for both pages? Make sure all CSS and JS loaded correctly before the page code execute. Look at [link](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2080700) may helpfull.

Comment: yes same master page is applied for both pages.